# Помогите пожалуйста сделать уведомление о входе на сайт в телеграмм

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

задался вопросом как можно сделать уведомления в телеграмме для разработчика (меня) при входе на сайт любого юзера.

```
<script>
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json', true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {

var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

var ip = response.ip;

xhr.send();

var text = `New visit to site!\nIP Adress: ${ip}`

xhr.open('GET', `https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendMessage?chat_id=${admin}&parse_mode=html&text=${text}`)

}
};


</script>
```

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте хранил у бота список IP адресов которые уже входили, чтобы бот проверял, есть ли адрес в наличие у себя в списке, иначе у вас будет очень много сообщений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Научитесь использовать [сниппеты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4619/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B) для вставки кода, чтобы было удобно читать.
2. Зачем создаёте через const, когда вам нужна переменная? Т.е. var или let.
3. Зачем запрос отправляете внутри функции, ещё до вызова? Он не вызовется.
4. Передаваемый таким способом токен - это не безопасно. Любой сможет его увидеть и слать сообщения. Я бы реализовывал эту задачу через backend.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json', true);
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if ( this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200 ) {
      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var ip = response.ip;

      var text = `New visit to site!\nIP Adress: ${ip}`;
      console.log(text); // эту строку можно удалить
      xhr.open('GET', `https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendMessage?chat_id=${admin}&parse_mode=html&text=${text}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: `Зачем создаёте через const, когда вам нужна переменная?` -- А `const` для чего по вашему используется, можете объяснить?